# Bash - Extracting lines from a file according to the indexes that are not listed on a list of indexes

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have two files.

File A: is a list of indexes.

```
1
2
3
4
13
14
15
16
19
20
```

The second file, file B contains some information that I want to extract depending on the indexes that aren't in the list of the file A.

File B:

```
@SRR4293698.1 5 length=35
GCTGGNCTTTGTGCATGCAATCTAGNNTCTTCTT
+SRR4293698.1 5 length=35
AAAAA#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF##FFFFFFF
@SRR4293698.5 5 length=35
GCTGGNCTTTGTGCATGCAATCTAGNNTCTTCTT
+SRR4293698.5 5 length=35
AAAAA#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF##FFFFFFF
@SRR4293698.8 8 length=36
CTGGCNTCTACAATATCTGGACGAGNTTCCGCATNA
+SRR4293698.8 8 length=36
AAAAA#FFFFFFAFFFFFFF.FF)F#FFFFFFFF#F
@SRR4293698.9 9 length=76
CTTCANATCATTTTCAGACTTTTCANACTGCTTGNT
+SRR4293698.9 9 length=76
AAAAA#FFFFFFFFFFF7FF7FFFF#FFFFFFFF#F
@SRR4293698.10 10 length=76
...
```

I would expect to extract lines 5-12, 17 and so on.

```
@SRR4293698.5 5 length=35
GCTGGNCTTTGTGCATGCAATCTAGNNTCTTCTT
+SRR4293698.5 5 length=35
AAAAA#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF##FFFFFFF
@SRR4293698.8 8 length=36
CTGGCNTCTACAATATCTGGACGAGNTTCCGCATNA
+SRR4293698.8 8 length=36
AAAAA#FFFFFFAFFFFFFF.FF)F#FFFFFFFF#F
@SRR4293698.10 10 length=76
...
```

I tried some thing, I found that :`sed -nf <(sed 's/.*/&p/' A) B` that works extracting the B file lines  that are in the A file. I was thinking to generate a `AllIndex - A` file, to get a new list of indexes, but definitely I think that there is another smarter way to do.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short **`awk`** approach:

```
awk 'NR == FNR{ ind[$1]; next }!(FNR in ind)' file_a file_b
```

The output:

```
@SRR4293698.5 5 length=35
GCTGGNCTTTGTGCATGCAATCTAGNNTCTTCTT
+SRR4293698.5 5 length=35
AAAAA#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF##FFFFFFF
@SRR4293698.8 8 length=36
CTGGCNTCTACAATATCTGGACGAGNTTCCGCATNA
+SRR4293698.8 8 length=36
AAAAA#FFFFFFAFFFFFFF.FF)F#FFFFFFFF#F
@SRR4293698.10 10 length=76
...
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed and bash:

```
sed -f <(sed 's/.*/&d/' numbers.txt) file.txt
```

Output:

```
@SRR4293698.5 5 length=35
GCTGGNCTTTGTGCATGCAATCTAGNNTCTTCTT
+SRR4293698.5 5 length=35
AAAAA#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF##FFFFFFF
@SRR4293698.8 8 length=36
CTGGCNTCTACAATATCTGGACGAGNTTCCGCATNA
+SRR4293698.8 8 length=36
AAAAA#FFFFFFAFFFFFFF.FF)F#FFFFFFFF#F
@SRR4293698.10 10 length=76
```

Comment: May also be written `sed 's/$/d/' fileA | sed -f - fileB`

Comment: Thanks to you too !